# Oracle initialization or shutdown in progress error

Tags: oracle

I installed the Oracle express edition (10.2.0) on a Ubuntu virtual machine (I am very new to Oracle Databases). Dpkg returned with a swap error, so i followed this howto to install oracle manually: http://blog.qakq.com/2010/01/oracle-xe-swap-space-workaround-dpkg-x.html

Now, when I run sqlplus and login with either system or sys, I get following error:

> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or
> shutdown in progress

I located some error log (/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/bdump/alert_XE.log), which has following error message:

> ORA-00202: control file:
> '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/control.dbf'
>
> ORA-27037: unable to obtain file
> status

This control.dbf file does not exist. Does anybody know why?

**Update:**
I now tried the fiels from oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb from a ubuntu/debian repository instead of the oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb from the oracle website, the control.dbf isn't missing anymore, but I still get the initialization error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to extend your swap (partition or file) at first. I am trying to install Oracle XE 10.2 on Debian Squeeze via (naturally using oracle repository):

```
aptitude install oracle-xe oracle-xe-client
```

> This system does not meet the minimum
>   requirements for swap space.  Based on
>   the amount of physical memory
>   available on the system, Oracle Client
>   10g  Express Edition requires 502 MB
>   of swap space. This system has 465 MB 
>   of swap space.  Configure more swap
>   space on the system and retry the
>   installation.

Check Oracle® Database Express Edition [Installation Guide for Linux](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25144/toc.htm#BABCCEGF). I suppose that also some kernel params (via sysctl and /etc/sysctl.conf) need to be changed.

Comment: I added a swap partition to my virtual machine and installed it via aptitude, like this it worked